# Delete child objects when parent reference is deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, hibernate, nhibernate, cascading-deletes

I have a following hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="Folder" >
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Owner"
         not-null="false" fetch="select" column="OwnerFK" not-found="ignore" lazy="proxy" />
    <property name="Name" />
    <many-to-one name="ParentFolder" column="ParentId" 
        not-found="ignore" lazy="proxy" not-null="false"/>
</class>
```

`ParentId` column is referenced to the `Id` of the same table, such that I know as to which parent the child folder has been created.

When I delete the parent, I want the child folders also to be deleted and if only child is deleted then the parent should not affected.

I tried `cascade="all"` on `parentId` column but that deleted my parent folders when I delete only the child.

Can this be achieved using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved using Hibernate. You will have to change your mapping a bit.

```
<class name="Folder" >
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Owner"
         not-null="false" fetch="select" column="OwnerFK" not-found="ignore" lazy="proxy" />
    <property name="Name" />

    <many-to-one name="ParentFolder" column="ParentId" 
        not-found="ignore" lazy="proxy" not-null="false"/>

    <bag name="ChildFolders" cascade="delete" inverse="true" fetch="select">
       <key column="ParentId" not-null="false"/>
       <one-to-many class="Folder"/>
    </bag>
</class>
```

Each element can have a parent and a child, so you will need a bag to fetch the children and a many to one for the parent.

So when you try to delete a parent, you have cascade="delete" present on your children to ensure there are no orphans.

Answer (score 0):

No NHibernate can not do this. You need to get the model to list structure and delete each object as your NHibernate maps to parent not child.